# Why don't I see tile-based 3D graphics?

Tags: 3d, tilemap

As we know, tiles can make it quicker to update large portions of the display at once, as compared with a bitmap. To put, say a letter, on the screen, the Commodore 64 typically does two writes (the screencode and the attribute), but the ZX Spectrum typically does 9 (eight bytes which make up an 8x8 bitmap, plus 1 for the attribute).

Recently, a demo for the SEGA Genesis was released called Red Eyes. My understanding is that the 3D scenes were rendered on a PC, and some kind of program converted these animations to a tileset so that each frame can quickly be written into VRAM.

But, however hard I search I cannot find any contemporaneous games for these retro systems which use a tileset to render (an approximation of) three-dimensional graphics. So is there a technical reason for that?

The nature of this question is such that it could be answered in the following ways:

- It wouldn't work because ...
- You obviously weren't looking hard enough because here's an example of a game that does that. Here's a disassembly or source code so you can figure out how it worked
- It might be possible, but you'd have to watch out for ...

Comment: On this site, we're specialized in answering how you can solve problems in your own game/mod development projects, rather than speculating which existing games used which solutions and why/why not. So: is this a technique you're thinking of using in your current game project? Have you run into any trouble making it work the way you want, that we might be able to help you with?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your comment. I am planning to use this technique in my game, yes. I have not yet run into any trouble because I haven't started yet. I suppose this question is preliminary research for me. Feel free to close it as off-topic if that's disallowed here.

Comment: For preliminary research, I recommend [consulting existing guides about the technique](https://jix.one/pushing-polygons-on-the-mega-drive/). If you run into any snags along the way and need something clarified/solved, please feel free to post here and we'll try to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I should probably clarify, the question about why this technique is rarely seen is a good one, just not one we're best equipped to handle in our format here. To put heads together to find examples of similar rendering techniques in games, or to speculate on why it's not seen, I'd recommend a more informal conversational forum, like GameDev.net's discussion boards, or retro gaming hobbyist / homebrew sites, or even our own [chat].